# How to solve the duplication of name between a macro and a function?

Tags: c++, macros

I am using Visual C++ 2008 to develop. In the project, I need include two headers (such as one is `aaa.h`, the other is `bbb.h`) that are supplied by third parties.

Unfortunately, there is a macro named "Log()" in the header aaa.h, and a function also named "Log()" in the header bbb.h.

As we all know, if the header `aaa.h` is before `bbb.h` in the source file, the function will be expanded in the pre-compile process and cause build error. Now, I have to put the header `aaa.h` after `bbb.h` in each source file. But there are many source files that need to include these two files. If I modify every file, it will need too much effort.

Actually, I only need to use the macro in my code. The function is useless for my project. But the header belongs to the third party, I can't modify it.

Do you have better methods?

Comment: What about `#undef`ining the macro in the places you want the function to be found by name lookup?

Comment: Sorry for curiosity but are the names really `Log` for macro (in a global scope in c++) and `aaa.h` for a header or just an obfuscation? It looks like really funny coding standards =)

Comment: I seriously doubt any header would be called `aaa.h` ;)

Comment: Have you ever heard about namespaces, enums, static class members?
I'm sorry you have to work with bad-designed code.

Comment: Create your own header `ccc.h` which includes `aaa.h` and `bbb.h` in the correct order and sorts things out; include `ccc.h` where you need the `Log()` macro.  Or designate an existing omnibus header to do the job.  Since the macro will effectively override the function, that's all you need to do, I think.  If you needed to use the function despite the macro, you could `undef` the macro, or wrap the calls in parentheses:  `(Log)(...)` invokes the function, not the macro.

Comment: I can't use "#undef Log" as the code call the macro will call the function Log actually. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you may create

```
// bbb_fixed.h

#if defined(Log)
# if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(_MSC_VER) // Maybe other compilers, maybe check version too
#  pragma push_macro("Log") 
#   undef Log
#   include "bbb.h"
#  pragma pop_macro("Log")
# else
#  undef Log
#  include "bbb.h"

// Now restore manually Log macro:
#  define Log // code from #include "aaa.h"

//#  undef AAA_H // aaa.h include guards
//#  #include "aaa.h"

#else // Lod undefined
# include "bbb.h"
#endif
```

And include `bbb_fixed.h` instead of `bbb.h`

but better would be to fix header `aaa.h` to not use such macro.

Comment: You'll probably fall foul of header guards in `aaa.h` preventing the restoration of the macro.

Comment: That's nice :-) (FSVO "nice")

Answer (score 0):

Use #undef Log, you may also copy the macro definition from aaa.h under different name so you will be able to use it without conflicting with the function from bbb.h.

Answer (score 0):

I've never faced a situation like the one you describe, so there may be a better solution, but perhaps you could simply `#undef` the macro whenever you want to use the function.

```
#include "bbb.h"
#include "aaa.h"

// ...

void foo()
{
    // I want to use the macro here
    Log();
}

void bar()
{
    // I want to use the regular function here
    #undef Log

    Log();
}
```

Comment: Thanks your comments. It is a good idea, but I can't use it The reason is that I use the macro __FUNCTION__ in the macro Log. If I use a function call the macro, the __FUNCTION__ will be always "foo".

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is why we avoid macros, because they are not scoped, meaning your options are incredibly limited.

You can:

- rename the macro;
- rename the function;
- `#undef` the macro before you ever mention the function.

…and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If Log() function is not needed by other things in bbb.h, remove Log() function from bbb.h

If files require bbb.h do not require Log macro:
Add a guard word in bbb.h; Check guard word in aaa.h; If guard word is present, undef Log macro. (Include bbb.h prior to aaa.h if both headers are needed.)

Example:

bbb.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_BBB_H
#define GUARD_BBB_H
#endif
....
```

aaa.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_BBB_H
#define Log()  // Log Marco
#endif
```

If both are needed, you may need to rename Log macro.

EDIT:
If function overload is possible, you can modify Log macro into a Log function.